# Redirect unauthenticated user to default URL with node.js and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have used node.js restify and angularjs to create a web app with no user administration. Now, I would like to add the user administration feature.

Users need to login to gain access to the web app. If they are not authenticated, they will be redirected to a default URL at `www.webroot.com/login.html`.

I am looking at the right node.js module to implement this feature but am at a loss at the moment. The 2 modules that caught my attention is `passport-restify` and `passport-http`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-restify
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-http

Here are some questions to implement this feature;

- Which node.js module can be used to implement this user login feature? What is the difference between the two?
- Is the actual URL redirecting action done using angularjs or node.js?

What are some sample code examples for user login? So far, I find documentation but few sample codes.

Comment: did you try passport.js?

Comment: @Yaakov, no, I did not. Getting confused. Isn't that similar to passport-restify and passport-http?

Comment: Use the middlewares.. it will helps you i think

Comment: "*What are some sample code examples for user login?*" Really..? You have 1k rep... you should know what is on topic and what is not in the site by now...

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide a authentication system to the application u need to protect the api server side and also the views i have used this sample

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

please check this might be usefull

Comment: I am using restify currently. Are there examples using restify instead of express?

Answer (score 0):

This module `restify-ensure-login` meets your requirements very well. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-ensure-login

> This middleware ensures that a user is logged in. If a request is
>   received that is unauthenticated, the request will be redirected to a
>   login page. The URL will be saved in the session, so the user can be
>   conveniently returned to the page that was originally requested.

Since your existing code base is in restify and this module makes use of restify, it is less of a hassle than to make use of most of the examples out there which use Express.